# Servlet and maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, servlet

При работе с сервлетами, в maven dependencies что должны поместить?

Comment: Прежде всего <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>, а остальное по необходимости.

Comment: @Caulfield Вам бы сначала выучить что такое `maven`, а не лезть в `Java EE`. `Java Core` хоть знаете?

Comment: @Caulfield а вы искали? Базовое руководство. 1 ссылка в гугле. что там не понятного? http://www.apache-maven.ru/

Answer (score 0):

в dependencies должно быть:

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пишешь в гугле "maven servlet", тебе выдаст ссылку на https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api (это центральный репозиторий мавена). Выбираешь там версию, например 2.5. 
Там буден написано, что тебе нужно добавить в pom.xml.
Копируешь этот кусок кода и вставляешь в pom.xml внутри тега dependencies.
В итоге это должно выглядеть вот так:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```